# Documenting VBA code for Excel Auto Complete

Tags: vba, excel

When writing a custom function to use in excel using VBA, How to write the documentation comments so that the excel automatically displays during auto-fill of a formula?

For example, when we start typing VLookUp, It shows what Vlookup does as a tool tip, shows the input variable names and if we press Insert Function from the ribbon, a dialog is shown with clear explanation of the function... How can we achieve that while writing custom functions in VBA?

Comment: You may wish to try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262421/how-to-put-a-tooltip-on-a-user-defined-function/4262521#4262521

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you must use [`Application.MacroOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195786.aspx) to register your function and its description, and optionally provide a help file to make the Help on this Function link work.

Not sure how to provide inline description for the parameters though.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this question a few times, and so far no answer has been provided.

I'm afraid it's just not possible (at least for Excel 2007, not sure about 2010).