# How to VBA show tooltip for UDF in runtime?

Tags: excel, vba, tooltip, formula, user-defined-functions

In excel, when you type for function Vlookup as `=vlookup( )`
the moment we press opening bracket `(` excel itself shows the arguments as the tooltip to be entered, at fourth argument it show as the `ComboxBox` or `DropDownList` for you choose option. I have a VBA function with many arguments, so great if can show tooltip as VLOOKUP and user will don't need remember promiscuous argument. How do i code?

Comment: See also [this post on Ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=66984)... which I now realise is almost identical to this question, but ended quite badly...

Comment: just look this. Not the best variant. But it is good. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41148157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible. Your best option is to use

```
Application.MacroOptions()
```

This method enables you to provide descriptions, help etc. when your UDF is added through the Function Wizard.