# Is there a way to make UDF that gives a description like the native Excel functions have when user clicks the Fx button?

Tags: vba, excel

If I type `=vlookup(` (or any other native Excel function) in the formula bar and then click the little Fx button to the left of the formula I get a Function Arguments prompt with all the available arguments.  In that prompt, below the functional arguments, is a one or two sentence description of the function and of each argument as you move your cursor from each argument's input box.

When I type in the name of my UDF and click the Fx I get an input box for all of my arguments but that is it.  Is there a way I can add those same helpful type of descriptions that native Excel functions have?

Comment: on the first page when googling `excel 2010 udf description`: http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/RegisterUDF00.asp

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, there is a somewhat hidden way to do that:

After you defined your UDF in VBA, go to the Object Browser in the Visual Basic Editor (<kbd>F2</kbd>). Here, in the top drop down, select `VBAProject`. In the window below, navigate to your UDF and right click it - select `Properties`:

[image]

In the properties, you can provide the description.

[image]

If you need further information, e.g. how to add the function to a certain category check out this [OzGrid article](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/DesciptionToUDF.htm)!

Comment: you're genius!) +1 for the trick - for future use) (oh God I'm sooooooo ugly and still don't know soooooooo mush...... doh...)

Comment: That looks good but for some reason whenever I type something in the description and then click OK it doesn't save what I typed.  Immediately after I hit OK I can go back to the properties and there's nothing there again.  Any ideas what is causing that?

Comment: I played around with different add-ins that I had some worked and some didn't work.  I toggled public function to just function and that, in some instances.  That isn't to say that it matters whether or not its public but something about removing "Public" may have made it work....very strange.

Comment: I think i understood the problem: the UDF description is only loaded once during Excel runtime. This, if you looked at it before in the fx window, Excel will not change it until you restart it!

Comment: @PeterAlbert - thank you for figuring out that problem... seems I don't have enough patience, and expected the change to occur **NOW** :)

Answer (score 36):

Type `=FormulaName(` into a cell and then press `Ctrl+Shift+A` and it will fill in the reference name of the arguments

Comment: Never knew this, very useful in general, +1

Comment: Me neither! +1. Nice bike.

Comment: LIMIT on length of the names of arguments in "SampleFunction" = 254 - NumberOfArguments. E.g., given `Function SampleFunction( Num1, Num2, Num3 )`, `Len("Num1") + Len("Num2") + Len("Num3") + 3` must be <= 254. The length of each argument name can be quite long - at least 88 characters (I have not tested longer argument names). <Shift-Ctrl-A> will show the full argument names in the Formula Bar. If you see `(..)` in the Formula Bar, you have exceeded this limit.

Answer (score 35):

I suggest further investigating the Application.MacroOptions method.  That method allows you to provide not only a description for the function, but also a description for each of the arguments.  For example, if you have a function called "SampleFunction" that takes two arguments, you can run the following and it will set you up nicely for using the fx button with your function.:

```
Private Sub RegisterMyFunction()
    Application.MacroOptions _
        Macro:="SampleFunction", _
        Description:="calculates a result based on provided inputs", _
        Category:="My UDF Category", _
        ArgumentDescriptions:=Array( _
            "is the first argument.  tell the user what it does", _
            "is the second argument.  tell the user what it does")
End Sub
```

Comment: this is the way to do it

Comment: LIMIT on length of the names of arguments in "SampleFunction" = 254 - NumberOfArguments. E.g., given `Function SampleFunction( Num1, Num2, Num3 )`, `Len("Num1") + Len("Num2") + Len("Num3") + 3` must be <= 254. The length of each argument name can be quite long - at least 88 characters (I have not tested longer argument names).The Function Arguments dialog box will expand properly to show the full argument names; and <Shift-Ctrl-A> will show the full argument names in the Formula Bar. `..` in the Function Arguments dialog box or `(..)` in the Formula Bar, indicates you have exceeded this limit.

Comment: Note that the ArgumentDescriptions parameter doesn't work for versions prior to 2010.

Answer (score 4):

Create function like I have created below: Function CompanyNames:

```
Function CompanyNames(CompanyCode As Integer, Data As Range) As String

CompanyNames = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CompanyCode, Data, 2, False)


End Function
```

Run below code once and you get the argument description in Function

```
Sub DescribeFunction()

Dim FuncName As String
Dim FuncDesc As String
Dim Category As String
Dim ArgDesc(1 To 2) As String

FuncName = "CompanyNames"
FuncDesc = "Returns the Company Name"

ArgDesc(1) = "Provide the Company Code"
ArgDesc(2) = "Select Range to lookup"


Application.MacroOptions _
  Macro:=FuncName, _
  Description:=FuncDesc, _
  Category:=Category, _
  ArgumentDescriptions:=ArgDesc
End Sub
```

Comment: While this is a fine answer, it isn't clear what it adds to the 4-year old answer of Kendall which also uses `Application.MacroOptions`

Comment: @John Coleman, It is a complete working example which makes it easier to understand.
However, he could have edited Kendall's answer.

Comment: Great answer, and the easiest one to follow as Stefan states.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT

I just noted you are creating UDFs in VBA thus my reply may not be applicable to your situation.

---

Have a look at one of the sample projects in Excel SDK called Generic.

It is a bare minimum skeleton to build upon

Right after the header include statements, you will notice a declaration of a two dimensional array where the rows represent the number of UDFs in your XLL and the columns are used for the description of the particular UDF

The first column is used for the name of UDF followed by the a string that contains the letters that represent the data type of each parameter in your UDF.

These columns may be used to put description text for each of your parameters in UDFs

The number of columns are determined by the UDF that has the largest number of parameters and the UDFs that have fewer parameters use empty strings as values that are beyond the number of parameters in such UDFs

But then these descriptions will be displayed in the dialog box that pops up when your click on Fx icon