# Excel not finding VBA Function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a VBA function to call in a cell in Excel, but the cell comes up as `#NAME?` when I enter `=MyFunction("a")`

In my VBA Module `Module1`:

```
Public Function MyFunction(anything As String)
    MyFunction = anything
End Function
```

in the cell:

```
=MyFunction("a")
```

Result:

```
#NAME?
```

What am I doing wrong here? When I start typing `=MyFunction` in the cell, Excel lists it as an option, but doesn't show the parameters and then produces this result.

This is in a 2007 `.xlsm` file.

Comment: FWIW, It works fine for me in a 2013 .xlsx file. Perhaps try putting the function into a clean spreadsheet to see if it can work for you at all.

Comment: Okay I made a new file and it worked, so it must be something weird with my document. I'll copy my data into there and try again.

Comment: You probably had made an error but left the function in the cell, since it's not volatile, it would not "update" by fixing the function, maybe?  For your paramters (tooltip), you could look at the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262421/how-to-put-a-tooltip-on-a-user-defined-function

Comment: I think when i saved the file as a `.xlsm` it didn't automatically enable macros on the file. I reopened the file and it prompted me to enable macros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *UDF* is in the correct place and is coded correctly and will be "recognized" **if macros are enabled** for the workbook in question!
 *Check your security settings.*

Comment: I had originally created the file as a `.xlsx`, and saved as `.xlsm` to enable macros on it. Now that I've re-opened the file it asked me to enable macros. Thanks!

Comment: I have made the same mistake about a million times myself !

Answer (score 1):

I have a macro-enabled file, I have Macro Security set to Enable All, I checked Trust access to the VBA project object model, I have my workbook in a Trusted Location, and I still cannot type in my function name or find it in the Insert Function dialog box. What other security settings are there?

This is on a recent unmodified install of 2016 x64 on Windows 10 Pro.

I have, in ThisWorkbook (Code):

```
Public Function TestJohn(derp As String) As String
    TestJohn = "test john " & derp
End Function
```

And I have in Sheet2 (Code):

```
Public Function TestJohn2(derp As String) As String
    TestJohn2 = "test john2 " & derp
End Function
```

Neither of which appear as usable functions for Sheet2.

Comment: Nothing so far, @MichaelZiluck.

Comment: I think I found the problem. We both were under the impression that you're supposed to put it in either ThisWorkbook or SheetX. What you need to do instead is right-click on VBAProject in the Project panel, and then select Insert > New Module. Put your function in there and it should work fine!

Comment: @MichaelZiluck you saved my day. This did work for me like a charm