# How to show the parameters of an UDF when typing the function in Excel-Vba?

Tags: excel, udf, vba

I have a custom `Excel` function but when typing it there is *no parameter* seems. How can I show the parameters of this function like default Excel functions like below?

[image]

**My Excel function:**

```
Public Function DiscreteEmp(ByVal rng As Range)

c = rng.Rows.Count
Dim bounds() As Double
ReDim bounds(1 To c + 1) As Double
Dim vals() As Double
ReDim vals(1 To c + 1) As Double
bounds(1) = 0

For i = 1 To c
bounds(i + 1) = bounds(i) + rng.Cells(i, 1).Value
vals(i) = rng.Cells(i, 2).Value
Next i

num = Rnd
If num = 0 Then
DiscreteEmp = vals(1)
End If
For i = 1 To c
If num > bounds(i) And num <= bounds(i + 1) Then
DiscreteEmp = vals(i)
Exit For
End If
Next i

End Function
```

Comment: You can't. That functionality is not exposed.

Comment: Really! I don't expect that there is no way to do that. How is it possible to call Excel the "Excellent" now!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262421/how-to-put-a-tooltip-on-a-user-defined-function