# Excel formula : Grab the column name corresponding to particular cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Excel Sheet]

In Above excel sheet i need a formula which will extract that particular column name where "1"  is present and enter that name in the corresponding cell. Example- In above Image each row corresponding to col "Tags" contain the column name whose corresponding cell contain "1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 4 column example you can use this:

`=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(IF(A2,$A$1,"")&" "&IF(B2,$B$1,"")&" "&IF(C2,$C$1,"")&" "&IF(D2,$D$1,""))," ",", ")`

For 7 columns, just add additional `IF` statements inside the `TRIM` following the same pattern.

The formula relies on `1=TRUE` to keep it short. The result each `IF` is followed by a space. The `TRIM` gets rid of extra spaces left when no `1` occurs. Finally `SUBSTITUTE` converts  into `,` so you get a comma delimited list.

Note that:

> TRIM strips extra spaces from text, leaving only single spaces between words and no space characters at the start or end of the text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

couldn't find a non vba solution for concatenating a range. So here is a UDF

```
Function conCatRange(ByVal criteriaRange As range, _
                        ByVal criteria As String, _
                        ByVal conRange As range, _
                        ByVal separator As String) As String

    Dim c As range
    conCatRange = ""

    For i = 1 To conRange.Columns.Count
        If (criteriaRange(1, i) = criteria) Then
            conCatRange = conCatRange & conRange(1, i) & separator
        End If
    Next i

    conCatRange = Left(conCatRange, Len(conCatRange) - 1)
End Function
```

1. criteriaRange = Range you want check for 1s,
2. criteria = 1 (in your case)
3. conRange = header range
4. separator = ","

if you want to add summary and parameter descriptions see this link
[How to put a tooltip on a user-defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262421/how-to-put-a-tooltip-on-a-user-defined-function)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your header range is A-K,

You could you use this formula from L2 onwards:

=IF(MID(TRIM(IF(A2=1,A$1,"")&IF(B2=1,", "&B$1,"")&IF(C2=1,", "&C$1,"")&IF(D2=1,", "&D$1,"")&IF(E2=1,", "&E$1,"")&IF(F2=1,", "&F$1,"")&IF(G2=1,", "&G$1,"")&IF(H2=1,", "&H$1,"")&IF(I2=1,", "&I$1,"")&IF(J2=1,", "&J$1,"")&IF(K2=1,", "&K$1,"")),1,2)=", ",MID(TRIM(IF(A2=1,A$1,"")&IF(B2=1,", "&B$1,"")&IF(C2=1,", "&$C$1,"")&IF(D2=1,", "&D$1,"")&IF(E2=1,", "&E$1,"")&IF(F2=1,", "&F$1,"")&IF(G2=1,", "&G$1,"")&IF(H2=1,", "&H$1,"")&IF(I2=1,", "&I$1,"")&IF(J2=1,", "&J$1,"")&IF(K2=1,", "&K$1,"")),3,1000),TRIM(IF(A2=1,A$1,"")&IF(B2=1,", "&B$1,"")&IF(C2=1,", "&C$1,"")&IF(D2=1,", "&D$1,"")&IF(E2=1,", "&E$1,"")&IF(F2=1,", "&F$1,"")&IF(G2=1,", "&G$1,"")&IF(H2=1,", "&H$1,"")&IF(I2=1,", "&I$1,"")&IF(J2=1,", "&J$1,"")&IF(K2=1,", "&K$1,"")))

This formula has a limit of 1000 character in column by the mid function. and it repeats 3 times the same formula because of the separator: ", " but if you dont mind the result format you can short it to one. just fill put 1 in columns and the column name will appear.

Hope this helps.