# Provide contextual help for users on custom functions in Excel formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a custom Excel formula using VBA. It has more than one argument and it can be confusing for other users (and even for me) to remember what arguments to put in the formula.

I know that default formulas show contextual help to users when they use it in a cell, like in this example with the French version of `=VLookup(`:
[image: Contextual help for RECHERCHEV function in Excel]

Question: Is there a way to do the same with a custom function? If not, do you know something else that can provide users with help on custom functions in formulas?

Here are some details that are probably irrelevant to the question, but might be useful for readers.

The code of the function looks like this:

```
Function myFunction(a, b, c, d, Optional ByVal e As Long = 1)
'some computations that return r
myFunction = r
End Function
```

The function is in a module in the .xlsm document (this can be changed). It works in formulas as intended, using `=myFunction(a,b,c,d)` in a cell. The function is easy on the CPU usage and uses mostly basic Excel functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can press `Ctl+Shift+A` after typing the function name and it will present the parameter names in the formula bar. If you want an actual tooltip to display, check out [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262421/how-to-put-a-tooltip-on-a-user-defined-function)